# NullReferenceException when comparing string read in from a file?

Tags: c#, file-io, streamreader

I have a clients.txt file with the "a a" as username and password. This should read from it and tell me if they exist in the file if I'm not mistaken.

Edit: On the second line of the clients.txt file I have "b b" as the username and password and they work fine.

Pic here:(new users can't post images)

```
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("clients.txt");
    int findIndex = -1;
    string userpass = "#";
    while (findIndex == -1 && sr.ReadLine() != null)
    {
        findIndex = userpass.IndexOf(txtUserName.Text + " " + txtPassword.Password);
        userpass = sr.ReadLine();
    }
    sr.Close();
```

Comment: Going to need to see some code. As text - no images of code, please.

Comment: Since the debugger is catching the exception, you should be able to look at the controls and variables on that line and see which one is null.

Comment: Good spot @dash - didn't see the .Password! That won't help, either! :o)

Comment: @ChrisRoberts I'm not sure what control is being used here - if it's a text box then I'd be surprised if it even compiles. FWIW You've nailed it re reading past the first line. Generally, people check while(!sr.EndOfStream) { userPass = sr.ReadLine(); ...}

Comment: So this is the kind of code we have processing sensitive user information?

Comment: @ChaosPandion I'm assuming this question is coming from someone learning the art, rather than something mission critical! I'm sure the OP will learn about hashes, salts etc. before getting so far as 'going live'!?

Comment: @Chris Roberts - I suppose you are right. Normally I'm a bit more forgiving but the `clients.txt` file worries me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your while() statement is gobbling up lines.  You'll need to move the ReadLine() call inside the body:

```
    while (findIndex == -1) {
        userpass = sr.ReadLine();
        if (userpass == null) break;
        findIndex = userpass.IndexOf(txtUserName.Text + " " + txtPassword.Password);
    }
```

Don't put passwords in cleartext in a text file.

Answer (score 2):

Your call to sr.Readline in your while statement will read (and disregard) the first line of your text file, so the first line being compared will be the second line of the text file, after the second call to sr.ReadLine.

You need to refactor your code so that you always capture the response from the call to sr.ReadLine.